# In the Google Developer's Console, I keep getting this error when I try to edit or create an OAuth Consent Screen

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

[I keep getting this error when editing or creating the consent screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhhZj.png)

This happens whenever I click edit settings on the consent screen. An error dialog pops up saying

"Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.

Tracking Number: #############"

After this, I can stay on the consent screen settings, but I can't add any scopes at all. I don't understand why it's happening, it worked fine before. But now for weeks it's been like this and I can't edit the consent screen.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because you don't have the authorization to perform edits, i.e. it is a permission issue. If you go to the link https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=YOUR-PROJECT-ID you should be able to see the Identity Access Management permissions assigned to your user, if there is any. You should find out who is the owner of the project and request editor permissions for the action you are attempting to do.

Comment: Problem is I am the owner. This is the same project that I've edited before, except now when I open the consent screen it gives me the error. I've tried this with other accounts too where I'd make a new consent screen and it gives the same error.